# Foreach loop position not working correctly

Tags: html, css, foreach, position, stylesheet

I'm trying to make a list with people that have been stored in a mysql database, however only the first database item is styled properly and the others are out of place. I'm fairly new with css and I probably made a mistake in the while loop or positioning.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnYy1.png
Image ^^

The code that I'm using is as followed:

```
   <div id="adminsummary">

<div id="admintitel">
    <p id="admintext">Admin Overview</p>
</div>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $steamid = $row["steamid"];
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/$steamid/?xml=1");
    if (!empty($xml)) {
        $username = $xml->steamID;
    }
    ?>

    <div id="admin">
        <img id="adminimg" src="<?php echo $steamprofile['avatarmedium']; ?>">
        <p id="adminname"><?php echo $username; ?></p>
     <!--   <p id="adminname"> SteamID: <?php echo $row["steamid"]; ?></p> -->
        <p id="adminname"> Rank: <?php if ($row["rank"] == 1) {echo "SuperAdmin";} else {echo "Admin";} ?></p>
        <hr id="hr2">
    </div>
    </div>
```

The stylesheet:

```
#adminsummary {
    background: white;
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 75%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float:right;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 77px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.59);
}

#admintitel{
    background: #343a40;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;


}

#admintext{
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;

}


#adminimg {

    border-radius: 25px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
}


#hr2 {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#adminname {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 25%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. So when you output something like this inside a loop, you either need to _create_ unqiue IDs (for example by using a loop counter or database record ID as a suffix) - or find a different way to address your elements in the first place.

Comment: an `ID` attribute *MUST* be unique within the `DOM` to be valid - unexpected side effects will be observed with duplicate IDs. As already mentioned by @Basil below you might consider using classes instead

Comment: Where does your while loop body actually end here? It looks like you are _opening_ one div element inside of it, but closing _two_ of them - no wonder that you don’t get any meaningful result then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the HTML and remove the IDs within the loop you can use a combination of classes with child/sibling selectors to assign styles in a cleaner way

```
<!-- these IDs are OK as they are unique ( presumably ) -->
<div id="adminsummary">

    <div id="admintitel">
        <p id="admintext">Admin Overview</p>
    </div>

    <?php

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $steamid = $row["steamid"];
            $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/$steamid/?xml=1");

            if (!empty($xml)) {
                $username = $xml->steamID;
            }

    ?>

    <!-- use classes &/or sibling selectors for cleaner html ~ no duplicate IDs though -->
    <div class="admin">
        <img src="<?php echo $steamprofile['avatarmedium']; ?>">
        <p><?php echo $username; ?></p>
        <p> Rank: <?php if ($row["rank"] == 1) {echo "SuperAdmin";} else {echo "Admin";} ?></p>
        <hr />
    </div>


    <?php
        }//close loop
    ?>

</div>
```

the slightly modified CSS using child selectors to assign styles within the `.admin` code block

```
#adminsummary {
    background: white;
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 75%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float:right;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 77px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.59);
}
#admintitel{
    background: #343a40;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}
#admintext{
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;
}


#adminsummary .admin img {
    border-radius: 25px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#adminsummary .admin hr {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
}
#adminsummary .admin p {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 25%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Damm, you really took the time. It worked. Thanks a lot, also made my code look a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting classes instead of id in your `divs` and `p` inside the `while` loop.

IDs are unique in `CSS`, that explain why the first row is styled, not the others.